# How can I inject my own response stream in to browser Internet Explorer

Tags: c#

Problem:

How to inject my own response stream to currently running iexplore.exe window..

Explation:

While user typing "www.google.com" in address bar of Ie.., Instead of showing response from 
Google Webserver...I want to show my own stream which  contains text like "

"The site blocked."

The important thing is I need all stuffs in Client Machine - **C# Windows Service.**

So how can I dynamically inject my own response to web client..?

Comment: Do you want to block some sites?

Comment: what is "_Explation_"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either control each explorer instance via COM interfaces (works for Internet Explorer only). *Maybe* there is a way to do so with other browsers using DDE.

or to set up a local proxy and implement filtering there.
In this case each browser should be configured to use the proxy.

For the simple reason of blocking sites you can edit %WINNT%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file and set the site's url to point to 127.0.0.1 (localhost)
In this case local machine just won't resolve, e.g. www.google.com correctly.

Or, ...

Answer (score 2):

[Web filtering software.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-control_software)

Comment: It's not. I take a literal question, ask myself "What is the OP trying to accomplish here?" and if it's easier to answer that then it's valid. It solves the problem above as a design decision, and the urgency of the matter demands approaching it that way.